# how to Get item from nested arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping web table and append scraped data to array. After append data to array i get array like this (there are arrays in array):

```
 [['Action'], ['1 796004', '35', '2022-04-28', '2013 FORD FUSION TITANIUM', '43004432', '3FA6P0RU3DR297126', 'CA', 'Copart', 'Batumi, Georgia', 'CAIU7608231EBKG03172414', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-02', '0000-00-00', '', 'dock receipt', 'YES', '', 'No', '', '5/3/2022 Per auction, the title is present and will be prepared for mail out; Follow up for a tracking number-Clara5/9/2022 Per auction, they are still working on 
mailing out this title; Follow up required for a tracking number-Clara5/11/2022 Per auction, the title was mailed out; tr#776771949089-Clara[Add notes]', 'A779937', '', '', '', '[edit]', ''], ['2 763189', '43', '2022-01-10', '2018 TOYOTA CAMRY', '43241241', '4T1B11HK7JU080162', 'GA', 'Copart', 'Poti, Georgia', 'MRKU5529916217682189', '2022-01-25', '2022-01-28', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-27', 'dock receipt', 'YES', '2022-01-28', 'Yes', '', '[Add notes]', 'A774742', '', '', '', '[edit]', ''], ['3 762850', '37', '2022-01-07', '2017 VOLKSWAGEN TOUAREG', '65835511', 'WVGRF7BP3HD000549', 'CA', 'Copart', 'Batumi, Georgia', 'MSDU7281152EBKG02708589', '2022-02-09', '2022-02-09', '2022-06-07', '2022-06-14', 'dock receipt', 'YES', '2022-01-20', 'Yes', '', '[Add notes]', 'A774650', '', '', '', '[edit]', ''],]
```

Now i want to get 4th(5) items (it is actually car model, e.g. for firs appended array it is "2013 FORD FUSION TITANIUM") from these updated data (array), i want to have :"2013 FORD FUSION TITANIUM, "2018 TOYOTA CAMRY" etc.

How can i achive that?

Comment: `[e[3] for e in l if len(e) > 3]` considering that ***l*** is your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop from the first index of the array to the end to avoid the first subarray.

At every iteration, select the ith subarray and get the 3rd index.

The result will be an array of the strings that you wanted.

```py
prompt = [
    ['Action'],
    ['1 796004', '35', '2022-04-28', '2013 FORD FUSION TITANIUM', '43004432', '3FA6P0RU3DR297126', 'CA', 'Copart', 'Batumi, Georgia', 'CAIU7608231EBKG03172414', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-02', '0000-00-00', '', 'dock receipt', 'YES', '', 'No', '', '5/3/2022 Per auction, the title is present and will be prepared for mail out; Follow up for a tracking number-Clara5/9/2022 Per auction, they are still working on mailing out this title; Follow up required for a tracking number-Clara5/11/2022 Per auction, the title was mailed out; tr#776771949089-Clara[Add notes]', 'A779937', '', '', '', '[edit]', ''],
    ['2 763189', '43', '2022-01-10', '2018 TOYOTA CAMRY', '43241241', '4T1B11HK7JU080162', 'GA', 'Copart', 'Poti, Georgia', 'MRKU5529916217682189', '2022-01-25','2022-01-28', '2022-06-20', '2022-06-27', 'dock receipt', 'YES', '2022-01-28', 'Yes', '', '[Add notes]', 'A774742', '', '', '', '[edit]', ''],
    ['3 762850', '37', '2022-01-07', '2017 VOLKSWAGEN TOUAREG', '65835511', 'WVGRF7BP3HD000549', 'CA', 'Copart', 'Batumi, Georgia', 'MSDU7281152EBKG02708589', '2022-02-09', '2022-02-09', '2022-06-07', '2022-06-14', 'dock receipt', 'YES', '2022-01-20', 'Yes', '', '[Add notes]', 'A774650', '', '', '', '[edit]', ''],
]

res = [prompt[i][3] for i in range(1, len(prompt))]

print(res) # ['2013 FORD FUSION TITANIUM', '2018 TOYOTA CAMRY', '2017 VOLKSWAGEN TOUAREG']
```

If I misunderstood the question, please let me know.

Comment: @CristiFati #broffutt Thank you guys, you helped me a lot <3